# String Formatting Easiest Prettiest

Tags: python, string, string-formatting

I find it takes quite a bit of focus, time an effort to format a string with the syntax I'm currently using:

```
myList=['one','two','three']
myString='The number %s is larger than %s but smaller than %s.'%(myList[1],myList[0],myList[2])
```

Result:

```
"The number two is larger than one but smaller than three"
```

Strange but every time I reach `%` keyboard key followed by `s` I feel kind of interrupted...

I wonder if there is alternative way of achieving a similar string formatting. Please post some examples.

Comment: You mean interrupted in terms of your typing flow?

Comment: This is not a duplicate.
Format is just one of the many possible ways to do a string.
Other options like concatenation are an option for this question.
Or perhaps something based around `string.join`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may be looking for [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format), the new, preferred way to perform string formatting operations:

```
>>> myList=['one','two','three']
>>> 'The number {1} is larger than {0} but smaller than {2}.'.format(*myList)
'The number two is larger than one but smaller than three.'
>>>
```

The main advantage of this method is that, instead of doing `(myList[1],myList[0],myList[2])`, you can simply [unpack](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) `myList` by doing `*myList`.  Then, by numbering the format fields, you can put the substrings in the order you want.

Note too that numbering the format fields is unnecessary if `myList` is already in order:

```
>>> myList=['two','one','three']
>>> 'The number {} is larger than {} but smaller than {}.'.format(*myList)
'The number two is larger than one but smaller than three.'
>>>
```

Comment: With `str.format` you can also do indexing within the format string rather than unpacking, if you want: `"The number {0[1]} is larger than {0[0]} but smaller than {0[2]}.".format(mylist)`.